# Where to find data on the use of statistical methods in Psychology?

Tags: references, history, psychology

I'm trying to find out, how the use of statistical methods in Psychology have been changing through history. For example, are regression models more popular now than ten years ago? When did simple non-parametric statistics, such as Mann-Whitney U, become less used (they seem to be used much less now than in 50s)?

**Do you know any papers or resources that provide such data?**

Comment: Andrey, this is a pretty broad question and unlikely to get you a satisfying answer.  Perhaps you can be a bit more specific about what type/field of psychology you work in and what types of data sets you keep and work with. (also what types of questions you're trying to answer) Then people might be able to help and let you know what types of methods work best on those types of questions.

Comment: "...and in other fields through history."  In other words, this question asks for resources about *all* of statistics!

Comment: I was looking for statistics on the use of statistical methods in different fields of science. E.g., when does regression models become widely used in Psychology as compared to Biology or Econometrics? Do people use ANOVA less now that 20 years ago? I understand that this is a broad question, and now I understand that it is not a good question for crossvalidated.

Comment: Now the question is more specific, so I hope it can be reopened

Comment: Try [this](http://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Psychology-An-Historical-Perspective/dp/0805835105/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1370011614&sr=8-4&keywords=history+of+statistics+psychology) and [this](http://www.amazon.com/The-History-Statistics-Measurement-Uncertainty/dp/067440341X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1370011614&sr=8-2&keywords=history+of+statistics+psychology). And if this  is a real thesis, I'd suggest narrow it down for 5 more rounds. As for your ANOVA question, try locate different thematic search engines (EconLit/PsycINFO) and perform a keyword search by year. Ask a librarian for help.

Comment: con'd: Also, Just because it's not called ANOVA doesn't mean it's not ANOVA. You'd need to investigate the trend of the tests at both functional and nominal levels as well. A brief interview with some people in quantitative psychology may also get you some good leads.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider the book chapter and the article listed below. I'm aware of reviews of subdisciplines, but not of the field of psychology as a whole.

**References:**

Austin, J. T., Scherbaum, C. A., & Mahlman, R. A. (2002). History of research methods in industrial and organizational psychology: Measurement, design, analysis. Rogelberg, S. G. (Ed.), *Handbook of Research Methods in Industrial and Organizational psychology* (pp. 3-33). Malden:Blackwell.

Goodwin, L. D., & Goodwin, W. L. (1985). An analysis of statistical techniques used in the Journal of Educational Psychology, 1979-1983. *Educational Psychologist, 20*(1), 13-21. doi: 10.1207/s15326985ep2001_3